# SAS Action to provide the class probability statistics

Tags: sas

I have a vector of nominal values and I need to know the probability of occurring each of the nominal values. Basically, I need those to obtain the `min, max, mean, std` of the probability of observing the nominal values and to get the `Class Entropy` value.

For example, lets assume there is a data-set in which the target is predicting 0, 1, or 2. In the training data-set. We can count the number of records which their target is 1, and call it `n_1` and similarly we can define `n_0` and `n_2`. Then, the probability of observing class 1 in the training data-set is simply `p_1=n_1/(n_0 + n_2)`. Once `p_0`, `p_1`, and `p_2` are obtained, one can get min, max, mean, and std of the these probabilitis.

It is easy to get that in python by `pandas`, but want to avoid reading the data-set twice. I was wondering if there is any CAS-action in `SAS` that can provide it to me. Note that I use the Python API of SAS through `swat` and I need to have the API in python.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean.  Show an example. Please post a simple example dataset (assuming that is what you meant by vector) that has your values. And post what result you want to get for that example input.

Comment: @Tom, I added an example.

Comment: So you just want to computing statistics on the calculated p_0, p_1, and p_2 ?

Comment: Yes, that is all

Comment: SAS generates a gazillion statistics. Is there some other name for these statistics that you can search the documentation for?  Perhaps SAS already has a way to generate this but uses a different name for it.  Otherwise just roll your own. Use PROC FREQ (or CAS equivalent) to get counts by your class variable. Then calculate your Pxx values and run the result through PROC MEANS to get min, max or other statistic.

Comment: Do you know which action-set contains `FREQ`?

Comment: You can use sas.submit to submit SAS code directly.

Comment: @Reeza, not sure what you mean by `sas.submit`. Is it a well defined action-set?

Comment: https://sassoftware.github.io/saspy/getting-started.html?highlight=means#submit-sas-code-directly-from-python-session

Comment: Link also shows how to get means so that should be easy enough.

Comment: @Reeza, well, I have already created a `CAS` server, loaded a dataset, and have several `CAS`-actions running. Now, I need to get those statistics. What you suggest is just loading an arbitrary old-sas function to get the probabilities. This will result a lot of over head for reading the data again. But, as I mentioned in the question, if I want to read the data again, I would use `pandas` to easily get what I need. So, `sas.submit` does not work for me.

Comment: Isn't it memory already if its loaded in CAS? So you're not actually reading anything again.

Comment: @Reeza I do not see `submit` in `swat` and it is loaded from `saspy`. What is `saspy`? How can I use submit with `swat`?

Comment: Please disregard my previous messages, I assumed you were using saspy, the official SAS python implementation. It appears you're not and I'm not familiar with swat.

Comment: @Reeza, I import `swat` and then create a server `s = swat.CAS(server, port)` and then load my action by `s.loadactionset(actionset="dataSciencePilot")`. 
`SWAT` is also an official `SAS` Implementation, see https://developer.sas.com/apis/swat/python/v1.4.0/

Comment: You are correct, they appear to have multiple implementations.

Comment: That interface looks very confusing to a non-python programmers. But it looks like it does have function (method?) to find the counts by values of a grouping variable. At least that is what I assume from looking at the name:  `swat.cas.table.CASTableGroupBy.value_counts`

Comment: @Tom, Thanks!. I read the corresponding doc, but still not sure how to call and use it.

Comment: @Tom If I know the number of classes, seems that `s.dataPreprocess.binning(table=tbl_name, vars=["bad"], nBinsArray=[2])` works. I am still working ...

Comment: @Reeza, I found a solution and posted it here too.

Comment: @Tom, I found a solution and posted it here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution and it works fine. It uses `s.dataPreprocess.highcardinality` to get the number of classes and then uses `s.dataPreprocess.binning` to obtain the number of observations within each class. Then, there is just some straightforward calculation.

```
import swat 
# create a CAS server 
s = swat.CAS(server, port)

# load the table 
tbl_name = 'hmeq'
s.upload("./data/hmeq.csv", casout=dict(name=tbl_name, replace=True))

# call to get the number of classes
cardinality_result = s.dataPreprocess.highcardinality(table=tbl_name, vars=[target_var])
cardinality_result_df = pd.DataFrame(cardinality_result["HighCardinalityDetails"])
number_of_classes = int(cardinality_result_df["CardinalityEstimate"])

# call dataPreprocess.binning action to get the probability of each class  
s.loadactionset(actionset="dataPreprocess")
result_binning = s.dataPreprocess.binning(table=tbl_name, vars=[target_var], nBinsArray=[number_of_classes])
result_binning_df = pd.DataFrame(result_binning["BinDetails"])

probs = result_binning_df["NInBin"]/result_binning_df["NInBin"].sum()
prob_min = probs.min()
prob_max = probs.max()
prob_mean = probs.mean()
prob_std = probs.std()        
entropy = -sum(probs*np.log2(probs))
```